# ERROR: Could not build wheels for coincurve, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm trying to run `pip install -r requirements-full.txt` on Ubuntu, but I'm getting this ERROR: Could not build wheels for coincurve, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects. Here is whole thing:

```
    pip install -r requirements.txt 
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Collecting coincurve~=15.0.1
      Using cached coincurve-15.0.1.tar.gz (223 kB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Installing backend dependencies ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
    Collecting green~=3.3.0
      Using cached green-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting protobuf~=3.19.1
      Using cached protobuf-3.19.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
    Collecting pycryptodome~=3.12.0
      Using cached pycryptodome-3.12.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
    Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from coincurve~=15.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.3.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from coincurve~=15.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.15.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: unidecode in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from green~=3.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.3.4)
    Collecting coverage
      Using cached coverage-6.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (212 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from green~=3.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.8.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: colorama in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from green~=3.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.4.4)
    Building wheels for collected packages: coincurve
      Building wheel for coincurve (pyproject.toml) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Building wheel for coincurve (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [63 lines of output]
          running bdist_wheel
          running build
          running build_py
          creating build
          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/_windows_libsecp256k1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/keys.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/flags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/ecdsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/context.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          copying coincurve/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/coincurve
          running build_clib
          /tmp/pip-install-dhco0a3q/coincurve_c753062167664507861b409485b2b53c/libsecp256k1/autogen.sh: 3: autoreconf: not found
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in 
              main()
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
              json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
              return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
              return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
              self.run_setup()
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
              super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
              exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
            File "setup.py", line 260, in 
              setup(
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
              return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
              return run_commands(dist)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
              dist.run_commands()
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
              self.run_command(cmd)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "setup.py", line 95, in run
              _bdist_wheel.run(self)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
              self.run_command('build')
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
              self.distribution.run_command(command)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
              self.run_command(cmd_name)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
              self.distribution.run_command(command)
            File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "setup.py", line 152, in run
              subprocess.check_call([autogen], cwd=absolute('libsecp256k1'))
            File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
              raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
          subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-install-dhco0a3q/coincurve_c753062167664507861b409485b2b53c/libsecp256k1/autogen.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 127.
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for coincurve
    Failed to build coincurve
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for coincurve, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried this too: [ERROR: Could not build wheels for coincurve, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71443172/19301329), and `pip install --upgrade pip`

Nothing worked, please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

if ur having the same problem, Install the requirements individually worked for me, heres the list:

```
coincurve~=15.0.1
green~=3.3.0
protobuf~=3.19.1
pycryptodome~=3.12.0
```